# How many strings does "abc"def"gh" parse to in shell?

Tags: shell, unix, echo, double-quotes

```
echo "abc"def"gh"
```

This will echo out `abcdefgh`.
Does the shell interpret it as 3 fields or just 1?

Comment: Short form: Quoting is a *per-character* attribute.

Comment: The answer is definitely 1.  Think about it: how could you get 3?  There are no spaces anywhere between the `a` and the `h`, so it's got to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Although that's an unusual use-case, it looks like just one. A way to find out. Make a script with:

```
echo "$1"
```

Then try it:

```
bash args.sh "this "isthe" first arg" second third
```

You get just:

```
this isthe first arg
```

Comment: *grumble* re: training folks to trust `echo` to emit anything that's actually true, *especially* with an unquoted argument (see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)). I'd strongly suggest `(( $# )) && printf '%q\n' "$@"` as a way to emit the argument list in unambiguous form -- with `echo "$1"`, one can't tell whether `$1` was `foo$'\r'bar`, or if it was `'*'` and there happened to be a file named `bar` in the current directory, or any number of other possible scenarios.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy While that's technically true, this is mostly from the perspective of the receiving script after any interpolation has happened, `*` included.

Comment: That's why I specified `'*'`, not `*`. Performing the expansion unquoted, you're doing globbing *again*, so even if the original argument passed on your script's command line was quoted, you're expanding it unquoted here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, I see what you mean and that's a very good point. Answer updated.

Comment: (BTW, you may find the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) interesting; for being widespread in popular use and idiom, it's a command with a *lot* of potential for surprises).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's true. Using `bash` effectively is like trying to handle a hedgehog. It's full of prickly things like this.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are no spaces outside of quotes it will be seen as one arg/field

So in this case the answer is one